# Why does filter_var() do not accept 0 as boolean?

Tags: php, filter-var

i had to validate a variable which should have boolean value either 1 or 0. i tried using filter_var(), the problem with the function is if it gets 0 as input it will return false, isn't 0 considered to be a boolean? if yes then why is the function returning false?

the following condition is returned true

```
filter_var(1, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

whereas if i use 0 as input it will return false

```
filter_var(0, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php:

> `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN`
>
> Returns `TRUE` for `"1"`, `"true"`, `"on"` and `"yes"`. Returns `FALSE` otherwise.

If you want to distinguish between `FALSE` as a value, and `FALSE` indicating failure, then you need to use the `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Because zero is boolean false?

Comment: It seems you don't really understand what boolean is or you didn't read the manual that explains the function. I suggest heading over to http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php and reading what the function actually oes.